# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError when calling function getConnection()

Tags: java

I am getting the error when compiling my project-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at testpackage.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:14)
    at testpackage.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:20)
    at testpackage.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:20)
```

Here is my first file code-

```
package testpackage;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class DriverManager {
       static Connection dbConnection = null;

       public static Connection getConnection(String String_url, String USER, String PASS) throws SQLException 
       {
          try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "driver load successfully"); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "driver load failed"); 
        }
          dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(String_url,USER,PASS);
          return dbConnection;
       }

    }
```

I called this method in another file-

```
package testpackage;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class testclass {
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{   
DriverManager Connection_getConnection = new DriverManager();
        Connection_getConnection.getConnection("database string url","username","password");
}
}
```

Note- I have used alert to debug the issue and find function calls recursively because i am getting alert one after one.

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent a wheel that seems to do the exact same thing as the original implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack overflow error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Answer (score 1):

Your `DriverManager.getConnection()` method consists in calling `DriverManager.getConnection()`, which consists in calling `DriverManager.getConnnection()`, ...

That's because you chose to name your class and method the same way as the standard `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling:

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(String_url,USER,PASS);
```

before ever returning a value, and since that is the method you're currently in you are recursively calling this method causing an infinite loop.

The `getConnection(...)` method is calling the `getConnection(...)` method which will never end and thus the `StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 0):

**The code will end up in an infinite loop. !!! That's why the your stack get filled.!!**

Fix :

Remove the

```
DriverManager.getConnection(String_url,USER,PASS);
```

called from the getConnection function will again call the same function. So remove that from `getConnection` function

Answer (score 0):

Your call

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(String_url,USER,PASS);
```

creates an endless recursion. You are importing java.sql.* but nonetheless your call calls `getConnection()` in your class.

Change to

```
dbConnection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(String_url,USER,PASS);
```